# How to record the sound coming out headphones from iPad pro?

Tags: ipad, audio, headphones, recording, screen-recording

I would like to know If I will be able to record using quick time player or other application you may suggest, both audio and video on my iPad pro with head phones connected !!

When headphones are not connected, there is no problem, i go to setting on the recording screen and i choose built-in microphone and it records all sounds around me

But what i want is while I'm using my headphones, when i want to record a video or any conference call, i want it to capture the audio from that call or video rolling on my iPad pro..